# WordPress custom post type Single.php?

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template

I have a WordPress custom post-type setup. I've created

```
single-[customposttype].php
```

However instead of displaying only the requested custom-post-type it goes to the URL, then displays all of the posts in the custom-type.

Here's a copy of the code i'm currently using:

```
<?php query_posts("post_type=shorts"); while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="header-promo">
    <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "mo_short_embed", true); ?>
</div>
<div class="content-details">   
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove `query_posts("post_type=shorts");` from your code.