# How to create a archive template for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, child-theme

I've created a custom post type using *Custom Post Type UI*  and *Advanced Custom Fields* plugins. The name of my custom post type is `article`.

I want to have a page which lists all the articles in a table format with the links to respective article. To achieve it, I've created a page and applying a custom template to it:

```
<?php

   $args = array('post_type' => 'article');
   $article_posts = new WP_Query($args);

   if($article_posts->have_posts()) : 
?>   
<table>
        <?php while($article_posts->have_posts()) : $article_posts->the_post(); ?>
        <tr>
             <td><?php the_title() // <-- Here I want to have a link ?></td>
             <td><?php the_field('published_in'); ?></td>
             <td><?php the_field('article_author'); ?></td>
             <td><?php the_field('published_date'); ?></td>
         </tr>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
</table>

<?php     
   else: 
?>

      Oops, there are no posts.

<?php
   endif;
?>
```

**Question 1:**
I don't know how to get link to each article :
I mean like `the_title()` which gives me title of the article is there `the_link()` which gives me link of that page?

**Question 2:**
Now assuming I got the link, when user clicks that link he'll be taken to that article page with my custom `single-article.php` but how to display content of that requested article?

Comment: I think what you want is a archive-your-cpt.php template which displays all single cpts on that page in a specific format. What exact format? Like a grid or portfolio style format with columns?

Comment: @BradDalton: I think My question is not clear so I've edited the `Problem`section of my question

Comment: @BradDalton: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2991/wordpress-custom-post-type-single-php has answered my second question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php while($article_posts->have_posts()) : $article_posts->the_post(); ?>
        <tr>
             <td><a href="<?php the_permalink(); // <-- Here's the post url ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>
             <td><?php the_field('published_in'); ?></td>
             <td><?php the_field('article_author'); ?></td>
             <td><?php the_field('published_date'); ?></td>
         </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: `the_permalink()` this is exactly what I was looking for.